# Trying to get property 'staff 'of non-object when test REST API from Postman

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

I'm trying to understand the reason of this error message from postman when test API.

When I am testing my REST API from postman, it gives me error

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property 'staff' of non-object
```

I try to find the problem but i can't find it. I kept searching for this but couldn't find an answer that will make this clear.

Anyone can help me on this?

Thanks!

This my code snippet

```
public function updatestatus($request, $leave, $is_api=0)
    {

        $status = $request->get('status');

        $user = $is_api? JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate():Auth::user();
        // $user = Auth::user();
        $staff= $user->ref_user;

        $applying_staff = $leave->staff;
        $applying_user = $applying_staff->main_user;

        //Approved
        if($status==2 && $leave->status==1)
        {
            $leave->status =2;
            $leave->approved_by_staff_id = $staff->staff_id;
            $leave->approved_date = new Carbon('today');
            $leave->save();

            if($user->centre_id)
                Helper::ClearObjective(10,$user->centre_id);

            dispatch(new EmailJob($applying_user->email,new LeaveNotification(route('staff.leave.show',$leave->id), $leave->statusStr)))
                ->onConnection('database')
                ->onQueue('emails');

            return response()->json(['Success'=>'Success']);

            //send email
        }
        // Rejected
        else if($status==3 && $leave->status==1)
        {
            $leave->status =3;
            $leave->status_rejected_reason = $request->get('reason',null);
            $leave->save();
            if($user->centre_id)
                Helper::ClearObjective(10,$user->centre_id);

            $leave_cat = LeaveCategory::find($leave->leave_type);
            if($leave_cat->leave_status!=0)
            {
                $leave_ent = $applying_staff->leaves()->where('leave_type',$leave->leave_type)->first();
                if($leave_ent)
                {
                    $leave_ent->leave_remaining += $leave->leave_days;
                    $leave_ent->save();
                }
            }

            dispatch(new EmailJob($applying_user->email,new LeaveNotification(route('staff.leave.show',$leave->id), $leave->statusStr, $leave->status_rejected_reason)))
                ->onConnection('database')
                ->onQueue('emails');

            //send email


        }
        //Cancelled
        else if(($status==4 && $leave->status==2) || ($status==4 && $leave->staff_id == $staff->staff_id))
        {
            $leave->status =4;
            $leave->status_rejected_reason = $request->get('reason',null);
            $leave->save();

            $leave_cat = LeaveCategory::find($leave->leave_type);
            if($leave_cat->leave_status!=0)
            {
                $leave_ent = $applying_staff->leaves()->where('leave_type',$leave->leave_type)->first();
                if($leave_ent)
                {
                    $leave_ent->leave_remaining += $leave->leave_days;
                    $leave_ent->save();
                }
            }


            dispatch(new EmailJob($applying_user->email,new LeaveNotification(route('staff.leave.show',$leave->id), $leave->statusStr,$leave->status_rejected_reason)))
                ->onConnection('database')
                ->onQueue('emails');

            //send email

        }

        // return reponse()->toJson(compact('leave'));

        return $leave;


    }
```

Calling API

```
 public function update(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->leaveApplicationRepository->updatestatus($request,1);

    }
```

Comment: In your `update` method you're passing `1` through for `$leave` but then in your `updatestatus` method you're trying to use `$leave` as an object.

Answer (score 1):

your updatestatus() need 3 parameter and your update() function pass only 2 paramenter;

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // please provide you leave data
    $leave = "your data is here";
    return $this->leaveApplicationRepository->updatestatus($request,$leave, 1);

}
```

Comment: Providing 1 is optional. The OP forgot to pass the leave.

Answer (score 0):

From the context that I can see, it is trying to reference the *staff* variable in:

```
$applying_staff = $leave->staff;
```

The *non-object* message will mean that `$leave` itself is the problem. Since you are passing in `1` to the call:

```
return $this->leaveApplicationRepository->updatestatus($request,1);
```

the `1` becomes the `$leave` parameter, and  that is not an object, hence the error.

Maybe you think that by passing in 1, it will find the correct model automatically? This is not the case. You need to load that model explicitly.